# SSH File Transfer Fails: No Route to Host

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ssh, data-transfer

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 fully set up. I can access it via SSH and it is completely configured.

When I copy files with FileZilla via SFTP everything is okay, but when I copy files with ES File Explorer on my Android, it stops after about 3-4 seconds. It just drops to 0.00KB/s.

When I try to reconnect, it says on ES File Explorer: `java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`
After that I can not connect to it from my Phone (ES File Explorer), FileZilla or Putty, and after a while it disconnects from my wifi network. (I can see the Pi in my Router Settings for about one more minute.)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

If ssh and filezilla work fine, then the issue might come from ES file explorer.  Did you try an other app with your android?  AndFTP worked great for me last time I needed to sftp to a pi.

Comment: Actually it must have something to do with the Pi, because I tried AndFTP, TurboFTP and every time I start to transfer a big video file the same Route to Host error occurs. Any other idea?